# How to preserve value in react component even when the component updates and rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to preserve a value in a react component even when the component has been updated and rerendered. I usually store it in the parent component, but in this case the parent component updates too so this is not an option.

In the following example I need to preserve the scrollTop position of a div element.
The way I do it is by storing the value in a global variable. Is there a way to do it without using global variables?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import ItemsList from './ItemsList';

const ItemsListContainer = (props) => {
    let elementRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        elementRef.current.scrollTop = window['scrollPos'];
    });

    function storeScrollPosition() {
        window['scrollPos'] = elementRef.current.scrollTop;
    }

    return (
        <div className="items-list-container" ref={elementRef} onScroll={storeScrollPosition}>
            <ItemsList context={props.context}></ItemsList>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ItemsListContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let elementRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    elementRef.current.scrollTop = window['scrollPos'];
});
```

By doing this you are setting the scrollTop value at each render.
If you want to preserve the value use useMemo instead

```
const myValue = useMemo(() => {
 return window['scrollPos'];
},[]);
```

the empty array means that useMemo have no dependecy so it will be evaluated only the first time

---

Using context:

```
export const CustomContext = React.createContext({});

export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return <CustomContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
       //wrapped code
    </CustomContext.Provider>;
};
```

inside any child component you can access to it by

```
const { value, setValue } = React.useContext(CustomContext);

useEffect(() => {
    setValue(window['scrollPos'])
});
```

---

using local store

just take a look at [lockr](https://github.com/tsironis/lockr)

```
Lockr.set('value', window['scrollPos'];)
Lockr.get('value');
```

Comment: I need to set the scrollTop at each render. This is the goal. My question is how to store the value of the scrollTop without using a global variable.

Comment: Well your options are: redux(but im not a fan) ,context (you can wrap your app with It but It you reload your app the value will be lost) ,local store in that case the value can be used anytime . Could that be An option?

Comment: i've updated the answer with more details